# How to register an e-person with rest-api in dspace

Tags: dspace

I want to create digital library with dspace-rest in this website :  https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSDOC6x/REST+API. I have found log-in api and authenticated successfully but i don't know how to register e-person. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking how to create a new eperson through the DSpace 6 REST API, then the answer is shown in the documentation page that you link to: there are no endpoints supporting any actions on the eperson registry. This is something that will change in DSpace 7 (see: https://github.com/DSpace/Rest7Contract/blob/master/epersons.md and https://dspace7.4science.it/dspace-spring-rest/#https://dspace7.4science.it/dspace-spring-rest/api/eperson/epersons ), which you may want to target anyway if you are starting a new DSpace implementation later this year.